# can I restrict access to root to only connected instance?

Tags: linux, root, user-permissions

It will mean that if I am connected another user that will try to authenticate as root will get an error.

Comment: So, these will be two different accounts or the same one `root`?

Comment: Lets say user Tom does su and connects as root, I want that user Bob when tries to do su and log as root to get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PAM module pam_limts can be used. Edit the `/etc/security/limits.conf` configuration file (maxlogins), and add the pam_limits module to the su service config.

Comment: erk, blocking root access does not sound like a good recipe for an emergency / system problems. And allowing remote access as root is just plain silly.